# Why Are @NonNull Annotation on FQN Not Allowed?

Tags: java, eclipse, non-nullable

Is it a bug in Eclipse or why I can't annotate parameters with fully qualified type names (FQN) with `@NonNull`?

```
    import org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.NonNull;

    public class Foo {
        // No problem
        public void bar(@NonNull String x) {
        }

        // Error: Type annotations are not allowed on type names used to access
        // static members
        public void baz(@NonNull java.lang.String x) {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not a bug in Eclipse. Instead, it has to do with the way annotation types are processed by the Java compiler. The explanation given below illustrates the issue.

First of all, the `@NonNull` annotation can apply to any use of a type (it is annotated with `@Target(ElementType.TYPE_USE)`). However, the type it applies to according to the Java Language Specification, is the type the annotation is *closest* to. This is not always what would be expected:

In the first case, the `@NonNull` annotation applies to the use of the type `String`, which is a valid type. As such, the annotation is valid.

In the second case, however, the annotation applies to `java`, which is a package name. As such, it is not a valid type, so the annotation cannot apply here. This will result in a compile-time error.

The Java Language Specification (paragraph 9.7.4) states:

> For example, assume an annotation type TA which is meta-annotated with just `@Target(ElementType.TYPE_USE)`. The terms `@TA java.lang.Object` and `java.@TA lang.Object` are illegal because the simple name to which `@TA` is closest is classified as a package name. On the other hand, `java.lang.@TA` Object is legal.

From this we can conclude that `@NonNull java.lang.String x` will not work, but 
`java.lang.@NonNull String x` will.

Also see [The Java Language Specification, Chapter 9.7.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.4).

Comment: Thanks for this very good explination! I think this is not well designed. `java.lang.@NonNull String` looks very ugly, but ok, it works :)

Comment: I would never guess that you can annotate like this: `java.lang.@NonNull String`